# Stack overflow error in C, before any step

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, stack-overflow

When I try to debug my C program, and even before the compiler starts executing any line I get:
"Unhandled exception at 0x00468867 in HistsToFields.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow."

I have no clue on how to spot the problem since the program hasn't even started executing any line (or at least this is what I can see from the compiler debugging window). How can I tell what is causing the overflow if there isn't yet any line of my program executed?
"The when the debugger breaks it points to a line in chkstk.asm"

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 on a win7.

I set the Stack Reserve Size to 300000000

PS: the program used to execute fine before but on another machine.

I have a database (120000 x 60)in csv format, I need to change it to space delimited. The program (which I didn't write myself) defines a structure of the output file:

```
`struct  OutputFileContents {
    char    Filename[LINE_LEN];
    char    Title[LINE_LEN];
    int NVar;
    char    VarName[MAX_NVAR][LINE_LEN];
    char    ZoneTitle[LINE_LEN];
    int     NI;
    int     NJ;
    int     NK;
    double  Datums[MAX_NVAR];
    double  Data[MAX_NVAR][MAX_NPOINT];`
```

This last array "Data[][]" is what contains all the output. hence is the huge size.
This array size "MAX_NPOINT" is set in a header source file in the project, and this header is used by several programs in the projects.

Thank you very much in advance.
Ahmad.

Comment: +1 for Stack Overflow reference.

Comment: You have an infinite recursion somewhere.

Comment: If you are getting an exception, then your compiler has not only started, it has finished, and you have run your program (which failed)

Comment: Depends so much on the code. Does your stack size really need to be so big?

Comment: Do you have a huge static scope array defined?

Comment: @Arafangion how come?... I'm using break points! and the compiler is not even reaching the first line?

Comment: @rerun oh yes I have a lot of them I guess.

Comment: @BugFinder Yes, I'm dealing with very big dataset. "over 100k rows by 60 columns

Comment: @TedHopp I don't think so because the program was working fine before.

Comment: @hoohaahi the complier doesn't run the program.

Comment: instruct your debugger to hold on exceptions ... it should stop right at the point where the exception is raised. (And please: do your self a favour and learn the difference between an IDE, a compiler, a debugger, and running/debugging a program)

Comment: no code = no useful info

Comment: if you've set a breakpoint at the first line of your main() function be aware that constructors for stack-allocated objects will run before main() executes.

Comment: OK, but 100k rows, at 60 colummns if you're converting from csv to spaces, you only need read a line at a time! You dont need it all in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, IDE != compiler != debugger.

Second, and no matter why the debugger fails debugging the application - a dataset that huge, on the stack, is a *serious* design error. Fix that design error, and your debugger problem will go away.

As for why the debugger fails... no idea. Too little RAM installed? 32bit vs 64bit platform? Infinite recursion in constructing static variables? Can't really say without looking at things you haven't showed us, like source, specs of environment, etc.

**Edit:** In case the hint is missed: Global / static data objects are constructed before `main()` starts executing. An infinite (or just much-too-deep) recursion in those constructors can trigger a stack overflow. (I am assuming C++ instead of C as the error message you gave says "unhandled exception".)

**Edit 2:** You added that you have a "database" that you need to convert to space-delimited. Without seeing the rest of your code: Trying to do the whole conversion in one go in memory isn't a good idea. Read a record, convert it, write it. Repeat. If you need stuff like "longest record" to determine the output format, iterate over the input once read-only for finding the output sizes, then iterate again doing the actual conversion.

Comment: Okay thank you very much, I changed one of the array size from 145000 to 32000 and it worked fine, but now I'll have a problem with handling all the data I have? I'm sorry I'm not good at this. what is the other option for handling such big database without using Arrays as big.?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the data?  It's surprising that you  need the entire data set in memory all the time.  Can you incrementally calculate whatever it is you're trying to?

Comment: @Andrew Myers: Please check the edited version of my question.

Comment: The distinction between the IDE, the compiler it launches, and the debugger it launches is pedantic.  Also, what OP describes as a user experience for the debugger is not a failure of the debugger.  By the nature of his bug, the debugger has hit a breakpoint in a module of the MS C library, during the setup prior to calling ```main()``` -- nothing's wrong with the debugger.  The solution to the user experience is to look at the call stack and understand what is ```crt0.obj```.

Comment: @Heath Hunnicutt: Proper communication is not pedantic, it's a necessary skill. Saying you got a problem "before the *compiler* starts" or "before the *debugger* starts" or "before the *program* starts" are three very, very different things. Say what you mean, mean what you say.